# Custom draw sprite in cocos2dx v3.2

Tags: c++, customization, cocos2d-x, draw

I try custom draw sprite in cocos2dx.
I use two ways:

```
void MyButton::draw(Renderer* renderer, const kmMat4& transform, uint32_t flags){
    sprite->cocos2d::Node::draw();
}
```

and

```
void MyButton::draw(Renderer* renderer, const kmMat4& transform, uint32_t flags){
    sprite->draw(renderer, transform, flags);
}
```

but both show same error:

> Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x2e0)

at line:

```
for(auto it=_children.cbegin()+i; it != _children.cend(); ++it)
            (*it)->visit(renderer, _modelViewTransform, flags);
```

in CCNode.cpp

Comment: That's not custom drawing. You're supposed to draw using Renderer and OpenGL, not call the draw methods of other nodes within the draw method. If you need to do that, use CCRenderTexture.

Comment: `uint32_t flags` this looks like a deprecated draw() function. I think it should be something like: `void MyButton::draw(cocos2d::Renderer* renderer, const cocos2d::Mat4& transform, bool transformUpdated) {}`